# Using multiple number to access array's element in javascript: whoy does this work this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list: `var a = [0,1,2,3];`

Then I mistakenly used a pair of numbers to access element, like this:

```
console.log(a[0,0]) // => 0
console.log(a[0,1]) // => 1
console.log(a[1,0]) // => 0
console.log(a[4,2,5,1,2]) // => 2
```

I thought it would either throw an error, return undefined, or use the first number it encounters, but instead, it seems the last element of the numbers is used. Why is it? Is there any reference I can consult?

For those who might wonder why I did `a[0,0]` : I was rewriting script written in python+numpy into javascript. That script deals with 2D-arrays, and numpy arrows `a[m,n]` to access `a[m][n]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that's how the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works; used as an expression, it yields the last value of the list, i.e.:

```
0,0         => 0
'foo','bar' => 'bar'
```

To access the second dimension of an array, you need to use the bracket notation:

```
a[0][1] // get first element, then second element inside that
```

Comment: Ah, so the "comma operator" is what's working in this case, reference being https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator (for example). Am I right? Thanks indeed.

Comment: @Yosh Yes, correct; I've added it in my answer, thanks for the find!